# Ubuntu 21.04: Kernel 5.11.0.22 broken on my HP Pavilion and won't boot

Tags: boot, kernel, hp

I'm always updating the kernel when a new version is available. So far that has never been a problem, but the latest version, 5.11.0.22, simply won't boot on my HP Pavilion! When starting, the Grub menu is shown, and if I select Ubuntu the HP logo displays briefly, then the screen goes blank and nothing happens. I need to select the advanced uption and then either 5.11.0.22 maintenance, or an older kernel.

I'm sure there must be a log somewhere explaining what happens, but don't know where to look.

On my other laptops (HP with AMD Ryzen and AMD Radeon graphics, HP with Intel Core I5 and unknown graphics) this kernel runs perfectly, so I'm baffled.

Any pointers of course much appreciated!

Comment: I haven't checked if the machine is available remotely via SSH, but my guess is that it is. This appears to be a graphics (driver?) problem, I wonder if the same thing happens to non-HP machines. Currently, I read two reports below of HP machines with similar behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to my question, but a temporary workaround. While waiting for a new kernel update that just MIGHT fix the problem, I have simply changed the default kernel to boot. Detailed explanation here: [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on a Lenovo Ideapad 520S-14IKB with kernels 5.11.0-22 and 5.11.0-25,  5.0.8-63 does boot.